# Fastest way to utilize huge vector (or array?) of objects in C++ vs. Java

Tags: java, c++, arrays, vector, bioinformatics

I'm writing some code for a computational biochemistry project, and I need to be able to have an array or vector with upwards of 10 million objects, and to run ~50-100 million monte carlo iterations where each iteration could modify an object from the list at random. I'm relatively new to C++, transitioning from Java (hoping among other things for more speed improvements).

My lab is in the process of ordering a computer with 128 GB RAM and 2 processors, but my current computer has 4GB RAM.The compiler I have at the moment is Visual Studio Express, though I've heard G++ is used by some of our collaborators.I'd be grateful for compiler recommendations if anyone has any, since I know some have run time performance differences.

My main problem is that I can't even get these declarations to reasonably compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#pragma pack(push, 16)      //Mostly ignorant about what this does
using namespace std;

struct RNAObject {
public:
    string sequence;
    string seqComplement;
    int bindingInx5Prime;
    int bindingInx3Prime;
    int length;
    enum type {MONOMER, SINGLE_STRAND, DOUBLE_STRAND, HAIRPIN, RIBOZYME};
};

void main() {
const static int maxSize = 10000000;
//RNAObject RNASoup[maxSize];  -Does not compile, stack overflow
//RNAObject* RNASoup[maxSize]; -Does not compile, stack overflow
vector<RNAObject> RNASoup(maxsize); //Compiles, but extremely slow already
cout << "Hello World";  //Stopped the compile before this line could happen
}
```

However, in my Java setup on the same computer, the following lines compile immediately, with no difficulty at all:

```
int maxSize = 10000000
RNAObject RNASoup[] = new RNAObject[maxSize];
```

I have a long way to go, so any pertinent recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have compilers errors don't hesitate to post them . good luck

Comment: I think you're confusing compilation with execution. Stack Overflows are runtime errors (although your compiler may experience them in odd situations). And `vector<…> …(N)` does the allocation at runtime either and the compiler has nothing to do with this.

Comment: You haven't really given useful information.   A description like "I need to be able to have an array or vector with upwards of 10 million objects, and to run ~50-100 million monte carlo iterations where each iteration could modify an object from the list at random." smells of "a bad architecture that maximises inefficiency".  Regardless of programming language.   How many objects does EACH monte-carlo iteration actually access?

Comment: It depends on what the object is. If it's a monomer for example, it might polymerize to another monomer with a certain probability. Then I'll need to pick another monomer at random from the array which has its own pitfalls because not all of the elements are monomers. But I've already worked out a fast enough way in my Java version. The other aspect, is that for every iteration, I need the concentration of each type of RNA object because that determines the probability of certain reactions. So it appears that for each iteration I need to traverse the whole array at least once.

Comment: Is each one of your 10 million objects going to have a unique value? If not, then you'll save a lot of memory by using 10 million pointers to objects (instead of individual objects), and only store unique objects which would be fewer. Look up "Flyweight Pattern" for ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Klitos, I like the idea as they will not all be unique, at least not to start.

Answer (score 4):

Your two pieces of code (C++ and Java) are not equivalent.

Your C++ vector declaration creates a vector of `maxSize` objects, and assigns a newly instantiated object into each of the `maxSize` elements (hence the slow startup time).

Your Java code simply creates `maxSize` *references* to `RNAObject`s. The equivalent Java code to your C++ code would be:

```
int maxSize = 10000000
RNAObject RNASoup[] = new RNAObject[maxSize];
for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++)
    RNASoup[i] = new RNAObject();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two places from which memory can be allocated: heap and stack. Stack is rather limited and is used for small objects, however it is much faster. Any declaration of the form:

```
Sometype someVariable;
```

Allocates a variable on the stack.

Any declaration involving `new` uses memory from the heap, which is almost always limited only by your computer's operative memory amount. Next declaration allocates a pointer to `Sometype` on the stack, and an instance of `Sometype` at the heap:

```
Sometype* someVariable = new Sometype();
```

Now regarding your code:

1). `RNAObject RNASoup[maxSize];` - creates one dimensional array of `RNAObject`s on the stack.

2). `RNAObject* RNASoup[maxSize];` - creates one dimensional array of `RNAObject` pointers on the stack.

3). `vector<RNAObject> RNASoup(maxsize);` - creates a vector on the stack, nevertheless vector stores its data at the heap, so it works. However vector is not very suitable for your use-case: it was designed for storing data, which length changes dynamically, and this feature drains a lot of performance.

So what you really want is:

```
RNAObject* RNASoup = new RNAObject[maxSize];
```

Which creates a pointer to the array on the stack, and allocates that array at the heap.

Also, from you question it is totally obvious that you don't understand even the basics of C++. You should learn the language before writing in it, otherwise you will be in a huge trouble very soon.

Comment: Thank you I realize I don't know the language well. This is a level of programming way higher than I've had to do before and I have very little formal training. That said, the exact line you gave me is still brutally slow and gives me an unhandled runtime exception...std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0041f300            I guess there's not much point in posting more until I've spent some time with Stroustrup's book but it bothers me that I can't even declare a single 10 million object array in the setup I have now.

Comment: @SpelingError, At my computer that line works for 1.3 seconds and finishes correctly. Moreover I've just created a similar code in java, and it took 2.4 seconds to initialize exactly the same array. By the way that code requires 1.2Gb of memory, are you sure that there is that amount available at your machine at the moment?

Comment: I have 4 GB of RAM on an OLD laptop (replaced 47 days before warranty about 4 years ago) so it's entirely possible that is the issue. However, like I said, in my Java version, it compiles without any issue, even on this old laptop. Whether it's because I'm doing something wrong or because there is a setup issue with the IDE or compiler I don't know. I deleted the #pragma line and got the same result. It's possible there is just something wrong with the computer but the successful Java result makes me think I'm missing some technical detail. I just don't know what it is.

Comment: @SpelingError, I guess I know why it has sufficient memory for Java, while insufficient for c++: http://jovislab.com/blog/?p=76. C++'s `string`s consume much more memory than java's empty pointers to `null` `String`s - try changing them to `char*` if possible.

Comment: Changing the sequence property to a char* compiles fast, and works. However, calling it a char array of length 100 (char* sequence[100]) won't even build for memory reasons. Clearly I've got a lot of design work to do, even on a new computer, because I need a  pool of 10 million related objects that aren't the same. A monomer doesn't have a poly-character sequence, but a polymer and double strand do. All this said, you've helped me solve the basic issue and it is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

your used string and vector in your code, so you need

```
#include <string>
```

and

```
#include <vector>
```

Also, because iostream, string and vector are all in std namespace, so you need to explicitly using this namespace by adding

```
using namespace std;
```

or use fully qualified names like

```
std::cout
std::vector
```

etc. for your code to work.

Comment: If you read the comments in their code you will see the code compiles and runs. They have a misunderstanding of compile verses runtime.

Comment: ...they also already have `using namespace std;` in their code.